# How did Starbug lose its landing thrusters in the Backwards novel?

Tags: red-dwarf

In the *Red Dwarf* novel, *[Backwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backwards_(novel))*, Starbug on backwards Earth mysteriously loses its landing thrusters, that mysteriously appear, rusted, underground.

It's explained that this had to happen, because in the future of the backwards universe (i.e. in the past), they would be unburied by the crew, untaken from the hermits' hut, unfound by hermits in the forest where they fell from Starbug, and finally, untear from Starbug as it leaves the backwards Earth. (Or, in normal time, tear away from Starbug on its way to land, found by hermits, brought in their hut, taken away by Red Dwarf's crew and burried underground.)

This is an explanation in terms of the future of the backwards universe.

However, how did it happen in the *past* of that universe? Starbug, searching for Lister (who was supposed to wait for them near the Niagara falls), landed (using its takeoff motors). But at what point did it lose its landing thrusters?

My theory is that it already arrived in the backwards universe without them (for whatever reason). But if that's right, how come the crew didn't notice before they left searching for Lister?

Comment: Probably some smeghead made a smegging awful landing which caused the thrusters to break off

Comment: I'd been thinking about that, and I think that wouldn't work, because in the backwards universe, everything happens backwards and it has to be possible in forward time. (An example: Kryten pulled a pick axe out from one of the hermit's chest. In forward time, that's Kryten stabbing him, which is possible (and it happens to be a murder).) However, if the thrusters were broken off at landing, in forward time, it would be Starbug taking off and the thrusters jumping from the ground, which can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You've hit the nail very firmly on the head (or rather, sucked the nail out of the wood with the head of your hammer). The thrusters must have fallen off of Starbug *prior to its emergence from the wormhole into the Backwards Universe*, in order to have been blasted *on* by the missile, shortly after they arrived.

Precisely how they ended up on the ground (e.g. before Starbug was even in that universe) remains an unsolved mystery. It's possible that another Starbug from a different timeline left them there, or that they spontaneously developed as a result of natural causes, much as a coal seam turns up underground.

We're left with the conclusion that such a thing is possible because the events of that universe allow the procession of event-to-cause, rather than cause-to-event, even where that creates a logical paradox. As Basil says, it's probably [best not to dwell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ul7zL-R3J4).

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't respond sooner, I had a lot of work. Thanks, that makes sense, the thrusters had to be there already, and they had to arrive without them. (In your answer, you mean either "blasted off by a missile shortly after they arrived" (if we go by the time direction of the backwards universe) or "unblasted on by a missile shortly before they left" (if we go by the normal time direction), right?)

Comment: @RedDwarfFan - Indeed. The missile caused an implosion that violently attached a set of thursters to their ship.